# Texture tile border deformed or displaced

Tags: c++, hlsl

I'm testing a selfmade ocean simulation in C++ and HLSL.
My problem is the texture tiles for the bump map have a weird border. (See screenshot)
This border seems to be the pixel 255 and 0 of a texture tile with the dimensions 256 x 256.

I tried to:

- use a Sampler instead of [] Operator
- change the rasterizer parameters
- change the Texture parameters
- checked my terms for the uv coordinates

Here's some Pixelshader Code:

```
float4 t0 = water_normal_texture[input.bump_uv_0] * 2 - 1;
```

And now after two weeks of useless searching I need a little bit help. Anyone seen this before and might give me a hint?

[image]

Comment: I don't know anything about HLSL but have some experience with OpenGL/GLSL. In OGL you can define what happens if the texture coordinate exceeds the boundaries (think it was called texture wrapping). One option is to repeat it and that might be the case you are encountering due to round off errors. If you have no self repeating texture you get those weird pixel lines. Try to explicitly clamp your tex coordinates or add some small offsets. Also try different options how your texture is wrapped at the boundaries.

Comment: Hi wychmaster, Thanks for your reply !  I already tested with a sampler that said "Wrap" or "Clamp": no result. I also tested with a width of 254 or 250 instead of 256: No better results. (should that have mentioned in the question - Sorry ) - regards, Charlie Brown